# spring+hibernate mapping class without xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

in my applicationContext.xml, this is how I map xml to POJO.  how to map directory to class file without required to create xml?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/custompackage/custom/spi/hibernate3/HibernateCurrentStep.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/custompackage/custom/spi/hibernate3/HibernateHistoryStep.hbm.xml</value>
                 <value>com/custompackage/custom/spi/hibernate3/HibernatecustomEntry.hbm.xml</value>
                  <value>user/custom/hibernate3/PropertySetItemImpl.hbm.xml</value>
                   <value>com/custompackage/user/provider/hibernate3/user/impl/HibernateGroupImpl.hbm.xml</value>
                   <value>com/custompackage/user/provider/hibernate3/user/impl/HibernateUserImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            .....
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

And you can further simplify things by converting

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
       <value>com.mycompany.sample.domain.Order</value>
       <value>com.mycompany.sample.domain.LineItem</value>
       ...
     </list>
 </property>
```

to

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany.sample.domain" />
```

in your `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` so now all classes annotated with `@Entity` in the `com.mycompany.sample.domain` package will be automatically picked up.

Comment: What should I  convert class mapping to in my AnnotationSessionFactoryBean?

Comment: @JiayiZhou Can you elaborate, I don't quite get what you are asking.

Comment: If in one of my Entity, I add a property that OneToOne mapping to another entity. What should I add in the spring framework xml configuration to get it work? You can check the details of my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956208/how-to-configure-hibernate-onetoone-mapping-using-spring-framework

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using XML mapping files, you can use the [Hibernate Annotations](https://www.hibernate.org/397.html) library which is based on Java 5 annotations.

As usual, you'll need to declare your persistence classes in the Hibernate configuration file (typically `hibernate.cfg.xml`), though you use the `<mapping>` element to declare your persistent classes:

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.sample.domain.Order"/>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.sample.domain.LineItem"/>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

If you are using the Spring framework, you can set up an annotation-based Hibernate session factory using the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` class, as shown here:

```
  <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource">
     <ref bean="dataSource"/>
   </property>
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
     <props>
       <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
       ...
     </props>
   </property>
   <property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
       <value>com.mycompany.sample.domain.Order</value>
       <value>com.mycompany.sample.domain.LineItem</value>
       ...
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Your bean declaration should be placed in DispatcherServlet Context? Or in another Spring Framework configuration file? And also when I have declared my persistence classes in hibernate.cfg.xml) should I also set up an annotation-based Hibernate session factory in Spring Security?

Answer (score 5):

You can use annotations on your class, though for Hibernate I'm not sure there's something built in (for use in Spring). [This thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=13796) should help if yo want to avoid yet more technology, but you could also use Java Persistence Annotations (JPA) in concert with Hibernate to accomplish the same goal.

[Here's](http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/hibernate-and-jpa-with-spring-example.php) a good tutorial for using JPA + Hibernate + Spring.

Answer (score 3):

@Pascal Thivent gives a very good start to what you want to do. For each Entity class you will need to annotate them. This is the docs that expalin the [annotations in Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/).

e.g. From the docs:

```
   @Entity
  public class Flight implements Serializable {
    Long id;

    @Id
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
  }
```

So in addition to what was mentioned by @Pascal Thivent you should get everything you need.