# Authentication using Spring 3 and Hibernate 3 (annotation based)

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application is based on Spring 3, Hibernate 3, MySQL. I read the Spring Security document and learnt that I can implement Authentication as given below,

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password, enabled 
          from users where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

    />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I understood above part but my concern is, in my application user table doesn't only store the userName, password and enabled field. It also stores first and last name, emailID, phone etc. On successful authentication, I want next jsp to populate all user details automatically and not ask user the same information which it will ask to non-regirstered user.

1. I want to use annotation based configuration and not xml based (unlike
   mentioned in spring 2.5 examples)
2. spring document doesnt use hibernate for security. Should i use
   hibernate or jdbc-user-service? if hibernate then how?
3. I saw couple of examples use customized UserService. Is that I need
   to do as well?

Can someone kindly advice with good examples? any references to other posts will help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now Spring Security is mostly configured without annotations, but you can use special XML namespace for simple customization of Spring Security.

You need to implement your own `UserDetailsService` which will be responsible for loading details of the user from persistent store.

`UserDetailsService` interface has just one method

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
```

After implementing and creating bean of your component you need to inject it:

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

More in Spring Security Docs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-userdetailsservice

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-authentication-provider

If you don't have information like `enabled` in your database, you will always have to put `true` value in your `UserDetails` object for that field.

Comment: thanks Mac. Hopefully using your explaination and below posts I can implement Authantication specific to my application.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361471/springsecurity-form-login-using-userdetailsservice-and-hibernate

Comment: Should you have any more problems, don't hestitate to write.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate/2701722#2701722