# How to configure Hibernate OneToOne mapping using Spring framework

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to use spring framework to configure Hibernate OneToOne mapping but cannot get it done correctly.

I defined 3 model,Interfaces: User.java, Organization.java, OrganizationUser.java and their implementation UserImplemenatation.java, OrganizationImplementation.java and OrganizationUserImplementation.java. Each model has fields as follows

```
User: userId, userName
Organization: organziationId, organziationName
OrganziationUser: organziationId, userId, roleId
```

It works fine at first. The configuration in Spring framework looks as follows:

```
<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>model.implementation.OrganizationImplementation</value>
            <value>model.implementation.UserImplementation</value>
            <value>model.implementation.UserSessionImplementation</value>
            <value>model.implementation.OrganizationUserImplementation</value>
            <value>model.implementation.OrganizationInvitationImplementation</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<import resource="actions.xml"/>

<import resource="services.xml"/>

<import resource="dao.xml"/>
```

Then, I want to add OneToOne mapping in OrganizationUserImplementation.java in order to get userName and organizationName. So I added two properties User user and Organization organziation in OrganziationUserImplementation.java:

```
package model.implementation;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import model.Organization;
import model.OrganizationUser;
import model.User;

@Entity
@Table(name="Organization_User")
public class OrganizationUserImplementation implements OrganizationUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "organization_id")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String organizationId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private int roleId;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="Organization_User",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="user_id")})
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="Organization_User",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="organizationId", referencedColumnName="organization_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="organizationId", referencedColumnName="organization_id")})
    private Organization organization;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOrganizationId() {
        return organizationId;
    }

    public void setOrganizationId(String organizationId) {
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

}
```

Then, when I run my project I got error message:

Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on model.implementation.OrganizationUserImplementation.organization references an unknown entity: model.Organization

I guess I missed a configuration somewhere. Because Hibernate considers the proerty organziation is the interface model.Organziation not the implementation model.implementation.OrganizationImplementation. But I have googled for a whole day try to find a tutorial regarding this configuration. But all I can find is Hibernation configuration for OneToOne. Does anyone know how should I configure it in spring framework?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you annotate all your implementation classes with `@Entity`?

Comment: Did you annotate `OrganizationImplementation`>class with `@Entity`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Otherwise, it won't work at first. When I didn't add property User, Organization to OrganziationUser. My project works fine. I can only get the columns from the OrganizationUser table. So I added User and Organization in order to get the userName and organizationName via OneToOne mapping. Then I got the error.